# How do I position nodes that are created using tikzstyle

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-styles, nodes

I need to draw a network topology diagram showing subnets, servers inside the subnets, and databases etc.
I have been looking at various examples of using TikZ to draw diagrams, but I am uncertain how to accomplish my goal.

I saw an example that used \tikzstyle to define the various shapes for my diagram, but I have been unable to find an example of how to position those nodes.

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{vm} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.0cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, textwidth=2.0cm, draw=black fill=green!20]
\tikzstyle{db} =  [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=red!20]
\tikzstyle {fs} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1, minimum height=2, text width=1cm, draw=black]
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (mydb) {db} (4,2) {myDB};
                \node (fs) {fs} (4,4.5) {FSStorage};
                \node (ws1) {vm} (1,4.0) {WebServer1};
                \node (dev) {vm} (1,5.255) {Dev};
                \node (ws2) {vm} (5,4.0) {WebServer2};
                \node (ws3) {vm} (5,5.25) {WebServer3};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{my Network Diagram}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
```

I realize I don't have any of the edges connecting the nodes, but I wanted to get the nodes positioned before I do anything else.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax used for nodes should be

```
\node [<style options>] (<node name>) at (<coordinate>) {<node text>};
```

but you're using

```
\node (<node name>) {<style options>} (<coordinate>) {<node text>};
```

So the style options are in curly braces instead of square brackets, and the `at` keyword is missing.

Note also that `\tikzstyle{foo}=[<options>]` is considered deprecated in favor of `\tikzset{foo/.style={<options>}}`. You also had two typos in the first style, `textwidth` instead of `text width`, and a missing comma after `draw=black`. See example below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzset{
  vm/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.0cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.0cm, draw=black, fill=green!20},
  db/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=red!20},
  fs/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1, minimum height=2, text width=1cm, draw=black}
  }
\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node [db] (mydb) at (4,2) {myDB};
                \node [fs] (fs) at (4,4.5) {FSStorage};
                \node [vm] (ws1) at (1,4.0) {WebServer1};
                \node [vm] (dev) at (1,5.255) {Dev};
                \node [vm] (ws2) at (5,4.0) {WebServer2};
                \node [vm] (ws3) at (5,5.25) {WebServer3};
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the @torbjørn-t  answer, I find the library `positioning`, which allow you to place a node relative to another without bothering with coordinates, very useful:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzset{
  vm/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.0cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.0cm, draw=black, fill=green!20},
  db/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, text width=6cm, draw=black, fill=red!20},
  fs/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1, minimum height=2, text width=1cm, draw=black}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
  \node [db                               ] (mydb)  {myDB};
  \node [fs, above       = 1.25cm of mydb ] (fs)    {FSStorage};
  \node [vm, below left  = of fs          ] (ws1)   {WebServer1};
  \node [vm, above left  = of fs          ] (dev)   {Dev};
  \node [vm, below right = of fs          ] (ws2)   {WebServer2};
  \node [vm, above right = of fs          ] (ws3)   {WebServer3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the code above, the `above = of nodename`,  `below = of nodename`,... allow you position a node at the distance `node distance` from the node `nodename`. You can also specify a distance between `=` and `of`. You can read the details at section "17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options" of the [PGF/TizZ manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).